# ESXi host time not syncing with NTP servers

Tags: vmware-esxi, ntp, time-synchronization

I have 2 NTP servers (AD 2003 machines) and some ESXi hosts, which are configured to sync time from these 2 servers. I found the time is not in sync between these hosts and servers. And time in each hosts vary from 2-5 minutes. I had done resetting the time in both the NTP servers and when checked, the hosts doesnt seem to sync with these NTP servers. Can anyone suggest me what needs to be done next?

Since host time is different, the same time is getting to my VM's too..

Comment: Which version of ESXi are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure you've both configured the NTP service by entering a time server and actually *started* the service.

[image]

The service should show up as "running".

[image]

Comment: Thanks ewwhite.. But my NTP server is running in all the hosts and i tried manually restarting that service too which I failed..